# Authentication Operations in Jersey Api

Tags: java, security, web, service, jersey

Do you have any tutorial or suggestion for Authentication because I don't really understand what's going on [here](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/security.html).

**My Entity class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "User")
@XmlRootElement
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "userId", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private long userId;

    @Column(name = "userName", nullable = false, unique = true, length = 89)
    private String userName;

    @Column(name = "userPassword", nullable = false, length = 34)
    private String userPassword;

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "senderUser")
    private List<Message> outbox;

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "receiverUser")
    private List<Message> inbox;
```

**My Repository class**

```
public class UserRepository {

private Session session;

public UserRepository() {
    session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
}

public void close() {
    session.close();
}

public User save(User user) {
    session.beginTransaction().begin();
    session.save(user);
    session.beginTransaction().commit();
    return user;

}

public User update(User user) {
    session.beginTransaction().begin();
    session.update(user);
    session.beginTransaction().commit();
    return user;
}

public User get(long userId) {
    session.beginTransaction().begin();
    User user = (User) session.get(User.class, userId);
    session.beginTransaction().commit();
    return user;
}

public boolean delete(long userId) {
    session.beginTransaction().begin();
    User user = get(userId);
    session.delete(user);
    user = get(userId);
    session.beginTransaction().commit();
    return user == null;

}

public User login(User user) {
    session.beginTransaction().begin();
    Query query = session.createQuery("from User where userName = :userName and userPassword = :userPassword");
    query.setParameter("userName", user.getUserName());
    query.setParameter("userPassword", user.getUserPassword());
    session.beginTransaction().commit();
    return (User) query.uniqueResult();
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<User> list() {
    Query query = session.createQuery("from User");
    return query.list();
}
```

**My Resource Class**

```
public class UserResource {

    UserRepository userRepository = new UserRepository();

    public User save(User user) {
        return userRepository.save(user);
    }

    public User update(User user) {
        return userRepository.update(user);
    }

    public User get(long userId) {
        return userRepository.get(userId);
    }

    public boolean delete(long userId) {
        boolean result = userRepository.delete(userId);
        if (result) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public List<User> list() {
        return userRepository.list();
    }

    public User login(User user) {
        return userRepository.login(user);
    }
```

**My Service Class**

```
@Path("user")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class UserService {

    UserResource userResource = new UserResource();

    @GET
    @Path("{userId}")
    public User get(@PathParam("userId") long userId) {
        return userResource.get(userId);
    }

    @POST
    public User save(User user) {
        return userResource.save(user);
    }

    @PUT
    @Path("{userId}")
    public User update(User user, @PathParam("userId") long userId) {
        user.setUserId(userId);
        return userResource.update(user);

    }

    @DELETE
    @Path("{userId}")
    public boolean delete(@PathParam("userId") long userId) {
        return userResource.delete(userId);
    }



     @GET
     @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_ATOM_XML)
     public List<User> list() {
     return userResource.list();

     }

    @POST
    @Path("login.json")
    public User login(User user) {
        return userResource.login(user);

    }
```

Comment: The only server side security Jersey offers is Oauth 1.0. Other than that you either need to implement it yourself or use an already established security framework on top of Jersey.